How to count up a number based on another column in a view?
I have a view like this (without the column number):

Now I want to fill the column Number as shown in the screenshot.
I wrote this SQL:
CASE 
    WHEN RESULT = TRUE 
        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RESULT ORDER BY Record) + 1 
        ELSE 0 
END AS Number

I have no Idea how to solve the ELSE part.
KR

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server - this may apply to others as well.
The easiest way to do this, in my opinion, is to use SUM as an analytic function - which makes the SUM do a running total.
For the CASE expression, make it simply result in '1' if true, or '0' otherwise. Then take the running total using SUM ... OVER (order by Record)
e.g., (also shown in this db<>fiddle
SELECT  Record, 
        Result,
        1 + SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY Record) AS Number
FROM #T;

